# Calculate angles of a polygonal shape given by its sidelengths

Tags: geometry, angle

Can someone tell me how to calculate the angles of this shape. The length of all sides are given.
I need to say that these are just example side lengths ; I need a formula for variable lengths.

[image]

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify the title you gave to your question in order that more people are attracted to it.

Answer (score 3):

The big issue is that the angles of a quadrilateral **aren't defined in a unique way** by its sidelengths because a quadrilateral isn't rigid.  Think for example to a square that can be given the shape of a lozenge.

For more see : ([What is the precise definition of a rigid shape?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/490242))

A convincing (so I think !) picture is the following one, where points $D$ and $B$ are fixed, constraining

- $C$ to belong to an arc of circle with center B and radius $4$.
- $A$ to belong to an arc of circle with center D and radius $7$.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Reminding the crank-handle movement in a steam locomotive...*

Even if you specify a fifth length e.g., length $AB$, you will not have this unicity. Indeed,
for each allowable value of $AB$ ($8.3\leq AB \leq 13.4$ in your example), using the law of cosines (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) you will get a unique value for angles $\hat C$ an $\hat D$ but not for $\hat A$ neither for $\hat B$...

Matlab program for the generation of the figure:

> ```
> n=26;% number of polygons
> d1=6.4;d2=4;d3=7;d4=12.3;
> for k=0:n-1;
>    a=pi*k/42;
>    d5=sqrt(d1^2+d2^2+2*d1*d2*cos(a));%length CD
>    b=acos((d3^2+d5^2-d4^2)/(2*d3*d5))+acos((d1^2+d5^2-d2^2)/(2*d1*d5));
>    plot([d1,d1+d2*cos(a),d3*cos(b),0,d1],...
>        [0,d2*sin(a),d3*sin(b),0,0],...
>        'color',[k/n,0,1-k/n],'linewidth',0.5+(k==12));
> end;
> ```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to calculate the angles by just knowing the sides here?

Comment: You mean in the particular case of these lengths ?

Comment: No, i mean with variable lengths (and maybe also adding more sides so that it is 
 a hexagon)

Comment: Se what I have added to my answer. The problem would be the same for a hexagon.

Comment: "all the possible quadrilaterals with fixed lengths have a common area...." That can't be right, Jean Marie. The quadrilaterals with all four sides of length $17$ can have area anywhere from $289$ down to as close to zero as you like. But maybe you mean sides *and diagonals* of given lengths.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson You are right. Thanks ! I correct it at once. I had mixed Heron (triangle) and Brahmagupta (cyclic quadrilateral) formulas...